# Difference between "Entity" and "Record"?

Tags: database, entity, record

While studying for my IT exam I came across the following sentence:

"A collection of fields that store information about a certain entity, is a record. A record is a whole row of fields."

..but I have always thought that the correct term for an "object" in a database is an "entity".

So is the correct term an "entity" or a "record"? Or are they the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In that sentence, `entity` doesn't refer to anything in the database. It's using `entity` to refer to a conceptual object, whatever thing in the real world the database record represents. For instance, if you have an inventory database, each row stands for a product in the warehouse, and that's the entity.

Comment: So the correct word for an "object" in a database is a "record"?

Comment: Yes. They're also called "row".

Comment: @Barmar thanks for information  - been getting confused with them time to time

Answer (score 0):

> An entity is defined as “something that exists as a particular and
>   discrete unit.” In terms of identity management, an entity is the
>   logical relationship between two or more records. [...] An entity is
>   also called a “linkage set.” There can be an unlimited number of
>   records in an entity or linkage set.
>   [Source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVY3_10.0.0/com.ibm.mdshs.inspuser.doc/topics/c_inspuser_recordtypes_records_entities_entitytypes.html)

Along these lines, an entity can be a set of records in a table or even across different tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that an entity concept is physicalised by 1 or more tables e.g.

1. a product concept might be encapsulated entirely in 1 table
2. a person concept might be spread across several tables, for example due to normalisation - all information relating to a person might not exist in the same table.